# How to handle high volume comparisons and then grand totals of scores

Tags: sas

I've got a bit of a problem that I am wrestling with and I think I am close but can't quite complete the task.

I have a dataset containing 16 rows/observations of values for 40 different people.  What I would like to calculate is which pair of people would result in the highest value if the higher of their 2 scores was taken for each of the 16 observations.

```
data test; 
input A B C D; 
datalines; 
22.82 17.74 5.94 19
10.16 17.74 23.12 6.62
10.62 10.76 24.72 11.3
28.06 6.92 22.26 11.34
;
run;
```

The above is a snippet version that is 4x4 instead of 16x40 for legibility purposes.

I've come up with a small data step and macro that handles the comparisons and new variable creation by appending the 2 labels together.

```
data test2;
set test;

%macro mk_combinations(first_var, second_var);
    &first_var._&second_var. = max(of &first_var. &second_var.);
%mend mk_combinations;

%mk_combinations(A, B);
%mk_combinations(A, C);
%mk_combinations(A, D);
%mk_combinations(B, C);
%mk_combinations(B, D);
%mk_combinations(C, D);
run;
```

This accomplishes what I was looking for showing that the combination of A and C results in the highest grand total, but with 40 variables, it's not feasible to manually call this macro that many times.

To complicate things, the field is not a single character but a first and last name field, I also have a numeric ID I can use, but after proc transpose it results in _1 thru _40.

So the first part of my question, is how is the best way to programatically call %mk_combinations?  I have tried arrays with do loops but can't get it to work.

The second question, is once I have that resolved, what is the easiest way to simply total up the 16 observations?  At first I thought that would be the easy part, but every method I know of relies on calling all the variables to sum explicitly, i.e proc means or proc SQL.

Any ideas on how to solve this problem?  Is there a better approach to this problem?

Comment: Do you have SAS/IML licensed?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me like you need to modify your data structure in order to efficiently solve the problem.  I'd try starting with a vertical structure and see if you can solve it that way first.

```
data have;
array people[40];
do _n_ = 1 to 16;
  do _t_ = 1 to dim(people);
    people[_t_] = 20*ranuni(7);
  end;
  output;
end;
drop _:;
run;

data have_vert;
set have;
array people[40];
do person = 1 to dim(people);
  people_value = people[person];
  obs_value = _n_;
  output;
end;
keep person people_value obs_value;
run;
```

That way you have 3 variables instead of 40.  Now do your analysis (I don't follow it well enough to complete it, but it should be easy enough).

You could also try just flipping (people as rows, observations as columns) if that's easier.

To answer the particular questions you have, both use the same technique.

```
proc sql;
 select name into :namelist separated by ' ' 
  from dictionary.columns
  where libname='WORK' and memname='HAVE' and name ne 'ID';
```

quit;

This uses SELECT INTO to create a macro variable (`&namelist`, the : replaces the & in the create stage so you could use a & in the creation to indicate some replaced text) which contains the results of the select query.  Separated by places a delimiter (usually space, sometimes comma or semicolon) between the results in the macro variable.  This particular query uses `dictionary.columns` which is the dataset containing all columns in all datasets in all libraries (hence the where clause).

So, your first question might be solved by using a join of dictionary.columns to itself, to create the cartesian product.  Your second would be accomplished in a similar fashion, creating the list of all variables to sum up for the PROC MEANS (or whatever).

Finally: consider reading up on some of the SAS PROCs that might be useful for the analysis you're doing rather than doing this all by hand.  I can't tell what you're really doing at the end of the day, but this strikes me as something one of the SAS/STAT procs might do for you.  Or SAS/IML.

Comment: Thank you.  I have SAS/STAT but not SAS/IML.  Do you know off hand what procs to look at as a starting point?  Also, My raw data has 1 record for each person and score, and I transposed by person.  Maybe I should transpose by score so that I have less variables?

Comment: If it's originally one record per person/score, then you're probably in the best data layout to begin with.  What are you actually doing with the data once this data manipulation exercise is completed?  Are you computing correlations?  Linear models?

Comment: Thanks for the responses Joe.  Here is a screenshot of how I solved it in Excel with the smaller data set.  The green cell shows the max sum that I am searching for.  http://i.imgur.com/IvnjqfO.png